# python tkinter frame inside a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and Tkinter.
I have created my interface but .grid doesn't seem to do what I want it to.
Instead of having a tidy look in the centre frame, the `LANframe` is floating in the centre instead of being close to the Quizes.
Also The statistics doesn't want to fill the remaining cyan space in the `Factframe` so it looks odd.
How can I neaten this?

> The main outlines work fine but when I Try to put 3 additional frames into those
> 3 main frames, they either overlap each other or they are in random
> places like show in the photo

```
 login= Tk()
    screen_width = login.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = login.winfo_screenheight()
    screen_height=str(screen_height)
    screen_width=str(screen_width)
    screen = screen_width+"x"+screen_height
    login.geometry(screen)
    login.title("Logged in as %s"%name)
    login.iconbitmap('icons/mainicon.ico')
    global min_w, max_w, cur_width, expanded
    min_w = 150 # Minimum width of the frame
    max_w = 300 # Maximum width of the frame
    cur_width = min_w # Increasing width of the frame
    expanded = False # Check if it is completely exanded
    # Define the icons to be shown
    global exits, settings, feed, profile
    exits = PhotoImage(file='icons/exits.png') # Make sure the image size is comparable to the minimum frame width
    settings = PhotoImage(file='icons/settings.png')
    feed = PhotoImage(file='icons/feed.png')
    profile = PhotoImage(file='icons/profile.png')
    login.update() # For the width to get updated
    global width1
    width1 = (int(screen_width)-200)
    global frame
    login.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    login.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame = Frame(login,bg=barcolour,width=120,height=login.winfo_height())
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsw")
    global frame1
    frame1 = Frame(login,bg="blue",width=width1,height=login.winfo_height())
    frame1.grid(row=0,column=5, sticky = "e")
    frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    width2 = (width1/3)
    global friendframe
    friendframe = Frame(frame1,bg="blue",width=width2,height=login.winfo_height())
    friendframe.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
    centreframe = Frame(frame1,bg="red",width=width2,height=login.winfo_height())
    centreframe.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="nsew")
    centreframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    centreframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    factframe= Frame(frame1,bg="cyan",width=width2,height=login.winfo_height())
    factframe.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="ns")
    timeheight=round(int(login.winfo_height())/5)
    timeframe = Frame(centreframe)
    timeframe.grid(row=0,sticky="n", padx=3,pady=3,columnspan=3)
    global clocklabel
    clocklabel =  Label(timeframe,bg =backgrounde,font="Ariel 40")
    clocklabel.grid(row=1,sticky="nesw")
    display_time()
    quizheight= round(int(login.winfo_height())/4)
    quizgoto= partial(gotoquizinterface)
    quizicons = PhotoImage(file='icons/quizicon.png')
    quizbutton = Button(centreframe,bg="green",image=quizicons,text="  \n  Quizes",compound="left",font="Ariel 40",command=quizgoto)
    quizbutton.grid(row=1,sticky="new",padx=3,pady=3,columnspan=3)
    LanFrame= Frame(centreframe,height=quizheight)
    LanFrame.grid(row=1,padx=3,pady=3,)
    Langameplayicon= PhotoImage(file='icons/LANgameplay.png')
    LANLobby = partial(LANGameplay, name)
    recentachieve = "Under construction"
    LANButton = Button(LanFrame,image =Langameplayicon, bg="yellow", text="   \n LAN Gameplay \n Under Construction",compound="left",font="Ariel 30",command=LANLobby)
    LANButton.grid(sticky="new")
    Achievementsicon=PhotoImage(file='icons/Awards.png')
    Achievements = partial(achievementsgained, name)
    AchievementsButton = Button(factframe,image =Achievementsicon, bg="purple", text=("   \n Achievements \n Recent Achievements: \n"+recentachieve+"\n"),compound="left",font="Ariel 30",command=Achievements)
    AchievementsButton.grid(sticky="new")
    Statsicon = PhotoImage(file='icons/Statistics.png')
    statsframe = Frame(factframe,bg="pink",height=login.winfo_height())
    statsframe.grid(row=1,sticky="esw")
    Showstats = partial(statshownow, name)
    timeon = "0"
    quizdone = "0"
    Avgscore = "0"
    statsbuttons= Button(statsframe, image =Statsicon, text =(" Stats: \n Time spent on:"+timeon+"\n Quizes Done:"+quizdone+"\n Average Score:"+Avgscore+"\n"),compound="left",font="Ariel 20",command=Showstats)
    statsbuttons.grid(sticky="nesw",columnspan=4,rowspan=5)
    global profile_b, exits_b, set_b, feed_b
    profilelabel = Label(frame,text='    ',bg=barcolour).grid(row=0,column=1)
    exitslabel = Label(frame,text='    ',bg=barcolour).grid(row=1,column=1)
    setlabel = Label(frame,text='    ',bg=barcolour).grid(row=2,column=1)
    feedlabel = Label(frame,text='    ',bg=barcolour).grid(row=3,column=1)
    profile_b = Label(frame,text='   ',image=profile,compound="right",bg=barcolour,relief=RIDGE)
    exits_b = Button(frame,text='   ',image=exits,compound="right",bg=barcolour,relief=RAISED)
    global set_b
    set_b =  Button(frame,text='   ',image=settings,compound="right",bg=barcolour,relief=GROOVE)
    feed_b = Button(frame,text='   ',image=feed,compound="right",bg=barcolour,relief=SUNKEN)
    profile_b.grid(row=0,column=3,pady=10, columnspan=2)
    exits_b.grid(row=1,column=3,pady=10, columnspan=2)
    set_b.grid(row=2,column=3,pady=50, columnspan=2)
    feed_b.grid(row=3,column=3, columnspan=2)
    frame.bind('<Enter>',lambda e: expand())
    frame.bind('<Leave>',lambda e: contract())
    frame.grid_propagate(False)
    login.mainloop()
```

[Unwanted Result]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBA0N.png

Comment: Can you please simplify your code. It's hard keeping track of all of those widgets.

Comment: Will try sorry :(

Comment: Why is your `quizbutton` on the same row as your `LanFrame`? Also why do you have `columnspan=3` for quizbutton?

Comment: I tried everything to make it align with each other so that the LANFrame is neatly underneath the quizbutton but it doesnt seem to work and the LANFrame is floating midway. So i tried to put it on the same row to see if it will fix it but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

# Create the left frame
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue")
left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

# Create the center frame
center_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
center_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
# Populate the center frame
time_frame = tk.Frame(center_frame, bg="white")
time_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
# Show the time+date
time_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text="20:44:22", bg="white")
time_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
date_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text="17/4/2021", bg="white")
date_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
# Show the `Quizes` button
quizes_frame = tk.Frame(center_frame, bg="green")
quizes_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
# Show the image on the left and the label on the right
quizes_img = tk.Label(quizes_frame, bg="green", image=None)
quizes_img.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
quizes_label = tk.Label(quizes_frame, text="Quizes", bg="green")
quizes_label.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
# Show the `Lan` button
lan_frame = tk.Frame(center_frame, bg="yellow", height=100) # Dummy height
lan_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

# Create the right frame
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="pink")
right_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

I rewrote part of your code and used `.pack` because most of the time it's either `side="top"` or `side="right"`.

This is how `.pack` works:

- You can specify a direction and it will be placed in that direction according to the last created widget. Imagine this case:

```py
 ----------
|          |
| widget 1 |
|          |
 ----------
```

If you call `<widget 2>.pack(side="right")` then the new widget will go to the right of the last one placed (`widget 1`) like this:

```py
 ---------- ----------
|          |          |
| widget 1 | widget 2 |
|          |          |
 ---------- ----------
```

Comment: is there a way of doing this with .grid as I used it for the main 3 frames as seen in the extended code above which works but when I try to repeat the process and make the quizframe, LANframe and the time frame right underneath each other neatly, it either looks odd like in the photo or doesn't appear. Also I would like the statistics frame to fill the whole left over space below but when i try to introduce  'height', it either stays like it is or doesn't want to fill it.

Comment: @pythontester It takes a lot of work to force `.grid` to expand the widget to fill the space. That is why I used `.pack`. You know that you can use `.pack` for the parent frame and `.grid` for the child frame, right?

Comment: Now I do, thanks. Might need to redo the whole thing but any way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .grid()
Try using place() and pack()
search on internet how to use them.
It might take little time to learn those and implement those but once you get use to it, You will find it is better way.

Comment: I heard that you can't mix layout managers in python so this would mean that I would have to replace the whole of my code

Comment: @pythontester You are right that you can't mix the `.pack` and `.grid` managers. You can use `.place` with `.pack`/`.grid` but generally it isn't good practise.

Comment: @TheLizzard gratulations for reaching 3333 reputation lol